# AngularJS - Link data from the ng-repeater and a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to modify data.

I have this array.

```
$scope.bar = [
        {a:  'aa',      b: 'bb',    id: 1 },
        {a:  'aaa',     b: 'bb',    id: 2 },
        {a:  'aaaa',    b: 'bb',    id: 3 },
        {a:  'aaaaa',   b: 'bb',    id: 4 },     
             ]
```

and this function, which should console.log the "selected data" and if it is modified console.log that.

```
$scope.foo = function(id){
        data = {
            a:  this.a,
            b:  this.b,
            id: id
        }
        console.log(data)
    };
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="x in bar">
   <input ng-model="x.a">
   <input ng-model="x.b">
   <a ng-click="foo(x.id)">click</a>
</div>
```

I am getting the correct data in the ng.models, but if I try to call the function. I am getting undefined for both a and b.

```
 Object {a: undefined, b: undefined, id: 4}
```

How do I link the data from the ng-repeater and the function?

Comment: just pass the whole object to your function. i.e. `foo(x)` and don't use `this` where you access your values.

Comment: Are you trying to match the object with the same id in your array?  `this` is used for constructors of new objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you already have the array where the data resides. The array is used by the `ng-repeat` so just query that array when you're in the controller.

```
$scope.foo = function(id){
        var data, i;
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.bar.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.bar[i].id === id) {
                data = $scope.bar[i];
                break;
            }
        }      

        console.log(data)
    };
```

OR

```
<div ng-repeat="x in bar">
   <input ng-model="x.a">
   <input ng-model="x.b">
   <a ng-click="foo(x)">click</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.foo = function(data){
        console.log(data)
    };
```

Here you are just taking that reference to the data named `x` and passing it to the function.

There are many different ways. Just remember that if you bind data to the view, that data still resides in the controller - because it had to come from somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Change your function call in the loop to:

```
<a ng-click="foo(x)">Hello</a>
```

and your function:

```
$scope.foo = function(x){
    data = {
        a:  x.a,
        b:  x.b,
        id: x.id
    }
    console.log(data)
};
```

or directly

```
$scope.foo = function(x){
    console.log(x);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, had to vote the other as acceptable answer, since he came first. You both gave me the correct answer tho! :)